# Getting an irregular-shaped object's pixel area in Photoshop

Tags: image, photoshop, photo, photos, photoshop-script

Is there a way to get an oddly-shaped object's pixel area in CS5? Eg. Circle/ellipse. Or, if there's some easy-to-automate way to do it outside of Photoshop.

I know it's possible to use a magic wand selection and see the height+width in the info panel, but that only works accurately for rectangles.

Thanks!!

Comment: Post this on superuser. This doesn't belong on StackOverflow unless you are interested in writing a program or Photoshop plug-in that will do this.

Answer (score 0):

Double click the layer thumbnail in the layers list

This will select the shape of pixels in the layer.